# Service probability for M/M/1 queue with reneging

Tags: queuing-theory, probability-theory

Consider an M/M/1 queue with arrival rate $\lambda$ and service rate $\mu$, where participants renege after a random amount of time which follows an exponential distribution with mean $\tau$. We neglect balking. Is there an expression for the steady-state probability that a participant receives service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steady-state probability of being served for an M/M/1 queue with exponential reneging times and no balking is
$$
p_s=\frac{1+z}{1+r(1+z)}
$$
where $r=\lambda/\mu$ is the service intensity, and
$$
z=\exp(r\mu\tau)\cdot(r\mu\tau)^{-\mu\tau}\cdot\gamma(\mu\tau+1,r\mu\tau).
$$
Here, $\gamma(x,a)$ is the *unscaled* lower incomplete gamma function:
$$
\gamma(s,x)=\int_0^x t^{s-1}\exp(-t)\;\mathrm{d}t.
$$
This result was originally given by [Ancker and Cafarian in 1963](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/nav.3800100112) (paywall)<sup>[1]</sup>. The equivalent formula for multiple heterogeneous servers can be found in [Section 3 here](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a444342.pdf).

<sub>[1] Ancker, C.J., & Cafarian, A.V. 1963. Queuing with reneging and multiple heterogeneous servers, *Naval Research Logistics Quarterly*, Vol 10, No 1, 125–149. DOI: 10.1002/nav.3800100112</sub>